# How do I create a 4x4 grid with partials only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

Say I have 16 objects in my collection, I want to create 4 rows of 4 each.

How do I do that using partials?

One way is to just use one partial on the main page, and have that partial render each row. Then inside that partial, have it 4 objects - but how do I actually do that such that it doesn't repeat objects and all this good stuff?

So the structure I am thinking is a partial (that produces 4 rows) and in each partial is another partial that produces 4 objects side by side.

But not quite sure how to pull that off.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<% @objects.in_groups_of(4, false) do |objects| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% objects.each do |object| %>
      <%= render object %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where can I find the docs for that? Not seeing it in the Ruby Array docs or Rails API docs.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it `in_groups_of` returns an array of the objects. How do I just get it to return a collection of objects, not an array.

Comment: @marcamillion in_groups_of documentation: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/3/1/new-in-rails-enumerable-group_by-and-array-in_groups_of/ and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of .. Railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of